# Subtotal with CountA always return 0 when trying to find filtered rows count

Tags: vba, excel

Ive sheet which is filtered using few criterias. Then I need to find the filterd rows count. So for that purpose I used following code.

```
rCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2:A500000"))
```

But rCount always shows as Zero

I dint understand what I did there wrong.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Does "Report_bar" exist? Do you use `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Pretty strange. Yea.. its exist.. When we take a Range count (Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2:A500000").rows.count), it gives the result

Comment: and what result does `Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2:A500000").rows.count` actually yield?

Comment: @DisplayName 499999

Comment: some _basic_ questions: 1) are you switching between multiple workbooks each having its own "Report_bar" sheet? 2) are you querying `rCount` right after its setting?

Comment: Are there actually any visible values in Report_bar!A2:A500000 after filtering?

Comment: @Jeeped, that was the ultimate _basic_ question

Comment: as a confirmation of the answer (not yet given, though) to last Jeepd question, you may run (backslash for new line) `With Sheets("Report_bar") \  rCount = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count \ End With`

Comment: @DisplayName Yes... Im doing that function from a different sheet. But before appying the autofilter, Im activating that sheet where the filtering takes place

Comment: @SandeepThomas, for further enhancements please answer all other questions you’ve been asked (see comments before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on your requirements and data. You are using SUBTOTAL 3 which is COUNTA

Just ignoring hidden rows:

1) Use **AGGREGATE** function with  3,5    (or 2,5  if want Count)

```
rCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(3, 5,Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2:A500000"))
```

**OR**

2) **SUBTOTAL** with 103   (or 102 if want Count)

```
rCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2:A500000"))
```

Notes on referenced items:

But you could also choose with AGGREGATE functions to ignore errors rows and a variety of other choices. Take a look through the different choices in the documentation.

**1) [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)(function_num, options, ref1, [ref2], …)**

Function_num 2  =  COUNT

Function_num 3 = COUNTA

Option 5 = Ignore hidden rows

**2) [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7B027003-F060-4ADE-9040-E478765B9939)(function_num,ref1,[ref2],...).**

102 COUNT Ignore hidden rows

103 COUNTA Ignore hidden rows

EDIT:

Thanks to @Jeeped for noting: "subtotal's 3 is documented as all rows with 103 to ignore hidden rows but in reality both 3 and 103 work exactly the same"

Comment: Still returning zero

Comment: Try the above options and if still failing please can you show the filtered data? You may have something else at work. The above functions are correct for ignoring hidden rows.

Comment: fwiw, subtotal's 3 is documented as all rows with 103 to ignore hidden rows but in reality both 3 and 103 work exactly the same.

Comment: @Jeeped I did not know that. Does that invalidate my answer?

Comment: No, although you might want to add a note that mentions that.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. Really dont know why.. Deleted that sheet and regenerated the data.. now its working..

Comment: As far as I know is the difference between Option 3 and 103, that 103 will also ignore hidden rows that were hidden by user and not by filtering.